# Given $k$ sequences: $(x_n^1),(x_n^2),...,(x_n^k)$ how can you build a sequence that these are its sub sequences?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

> Given $k$ sequences: $(x_n^1),(x_n^2),...,(x_n^k)$ how can you build a sequence that these are its sub sequences ?

I notice that each of those sequences have a different limit but other than that I have no idea on where to start.

Comment: Of course, the constructed sequence will have other subsequences... Anyway: you could start with $x_1^1, x^2_1, \ldots, x^k_1$ ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define
$$X_j :=x_{(j\ {\rm div}\ k) + 1}^{(j\ {\rm mod}\ k) + 1}$$
Where $j = k \cdot (j\ {\rm div}\ k) + (j\ {\rm mod}\ k)$ is the unique decomposition with
$$j\ {\rm mod}\ k \in \{0, \ldots, k-1\}\text{ and }j\ {\rm div}\ k \in \mathbb N_0$$
The sequence $X := (X_j)_{j=0}^\infty$ then starts at $0$ and has all of $x^1, x^2, \ldots x^k$ as subsequences.

---

Note that $X$ will have a limit iff all $x^j, j=1\ldots k$ have the same limit and then
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} X_n = \lim_{n\to\infty} x^j_n \qquad \forall j\in\{1, \ldots,k \}$$

---

To visualise, see
$$X=(x_1^1, x_1^2, x_1^3, \ldots, x_1^k, x_2^1, x_2^2, \ldots)$$

Comment: Decomposition ? div ? why modulo here ? This solution may be too advanced for me.

Comment: Just write $j = q\cdot k + r$ (Division with rest). The functions are just to make it as correct as possible.
$j\ {\rm mod}\ k$ just cycles through the values $0,1,2,\ldots, k-1,0,1,\ldots$ whereas $j\ {\rm div}\ k$ starts at $0$ and increases by $1$ every $k$ numbers, i.e.
$\underbrace{0,0,0,0\ldots,0}_{k\text{ times}},\underbrace{1,1,\ldots,1}_{k\text{ times}}, \ldots$

Comment: Ah I get it now. You probably mean division with remainder. What is decomposition ?

Comment: @GinKin Decomposition is only a general term for splitting something (in this case, $j$)